# Quick smoke animation by python invisible - Working by GUI

Tags: python, scripting, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

Opening Blender > General > Object > Add> Quick Smoke results in an animation displaying the moving smoke. As expected.

Doing the same in python, displays the the smoke in frame 1, yet it disappears after hitting `SPACE` (start animation)

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import *
from math import *

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='FLUID')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
bpy.ops.object.quick_smoke()
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].domain_settings.cache_type = 'ALL'
# bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].domain_settings.cache_directory = '/tmp/blender_leBmMS/cache_foo'
bpy.ops.fluid.bake_all()
```

Comment: Your script works when invoked from the Python console in 2.93.5.  What error messages show up in the terminal or info window?

Comment: It works fine when I run it as a script as well.  Perhaps share your blend file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  The only time it fails in anyway it's when I run the script twice. The second time fails because there's already a fluid simulation modifier on the cube.

Comment: Ah, I think I might have it.  Your script will fail the way yo describe, if the cube is not the active object, because quick_smoke needs an active object.

Comment: As per @MartyFouts, after you assign the object "Cube" to the variable `cube`, add the statement `cube.select_set(True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DNR You appear to have hit several errors in a row in your testing, because you're not resetting the scene between tests.

As written, there are (at least) three ways your script can fail.

1. There is no cube in the scene or at least none named `Cube`.  But that gives a different error than you described.  In the terminal window you'll see error messages that look like this at the end

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stupi\Downloads\foo.blend\Text", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Cube" not found'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

2. The cube already has a fluid modifier.  But in this case, the simulation will run.  The only error indication will be the message below.  But in this case you'll have two smoke domains in your outliner view.

```
Warning: Only one modifier of this type is allowed
```

3. The cube exists, is named `Cube`, does not already have a fluid modifier but is not the active object.  This too gives a message and doesn't create the domain.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stupi\Downloads\foo.blend\Text", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Select at least one mesh object

Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

If you want a simpler script that doesn't do error handling you can replace your script with

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.quick_smoke()
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].domain_settings.cache_type = 'ALL'
bpy.ops.fluid.bake_all()
```

Or you can write a script that checks for the named error conditions:

```
import bpy

def smoke_setup():
    object = bpy.context.object
    if not object:
        # There is no active object
        # you may want error handling or messaging here
        return

    if object.type != "MESH":
        # The active object is not a mesh
        # you may want error handling or messaging here
        return

    if object.modifiers.get('Fluid'):
        # The active object already has a Fluid modifier
        # You may want error handling or messaging here
        return

    object.quick_smoke()
    object.modifiers["Fluid"].domain_settings.cache_type = 'ALL'
    # object.modifiers["Fluid"].domain_settings.cache_directory = '/tmp/blender_leBmMS/cache_foo'
    bpy.ops.fluid.bake_all()


smoke_setup()
```